# How to change the font color and background color of visual studio's console

Tags: visual-studio, cmd, windows-11

As the title asks，I can't find the relevant settings, in `windows 10`, visual studio's F5 will start a `cmd.exe`, I can right click on it to set all this[(as this said)](https://peterdaugaardrasmussen.com/2021/01/02/how-to-set-the-colors-of-the-console-in-visual-studio/), but in windows terminal, I can't see the corresponding option.
Can anyone tell me where it is? Or give me a definite answer whether it is "not currently developed", where can I confirm this?
[image]